# I get err tips: Error 405 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am did this testing as following:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Logging+in+to+SimpleSAMLphp+using+Identity+Server

and I did all step  .

I clicked "wso2-sp" button:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsMhF.png)

Then, I got this following err：

Error 405 - Method Not Allowed

https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do?RelayState=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsimplesaml%2Fwww%2Fmodule.php%2Fcore%2Fauthenticate.php%3Fas%3Dwso2-sp&commonAuthCallerPath=%2Fsamlsso&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=2ff2a270-fd75-420b-bfe2-04cc01edf78c&relyingParty=simplesaml&type=samlsso&sp=simplesaml&isSaaSApp=false&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator%3ALOCAL

I guess that I should enable SSO function? and I not sure it.i not know how to enable SSO.

Could you give me any suggestion?

Thanks

henry

Comment: What is the IS version that you use?

Comment: my version is :  wso2is-5.12.0-alpha9